# Wrong data in python list

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to calculate a difference beetwen two string variables from lists `s` and `__prev_data.` For that I
create a temporary variable `output` with data form `s`, convert `output[0]` and `__prev_data[]` them from str to int and calculate. After some operations with this data I put `s`
to `__prev_data` without any operations with `s` whatsoever. But, somehow, `s` suddenly becomes equal to `output` and ruins whole script. Here's my code:

```
    def __printCSVRow(self): #Print data to file
        s = []
        for full_label in self.__csv_columns:
            v = self.__csv_data[full_label]
            if v == None:
                v = self.__csv_null
            else:
                v = str(v)

            #if full_label != self.__time_msg:
            if len(v) > 10:
                v = v[:8]
            elif len(v) < 8 and len(v) > 3:
                v += "\t"
            elif len(v) <= 3:
                v += "\t\t"
            s.append(v)
        output = s
        if self.__prev_data: #if __prev_data is not empty
            diff = ((int(output[0]) - int(self.__prev_data[0])) // 100000) #calculate the difference
            for i in range(1, diff + 1): #Some operations
                output[0] = str(self.__msg_count * 100)
                self.__msg_count += 1 #increase __msg_count
                if self.__file != None: #print to file
                    print(self.__csv_delim.join(output), file=self.__file)
                else:
                    print(self.__csv_delim.join(output))
        else: #if __prev_data is empty
            output[0] = str(self.__msg_count) #set output[0] to 0
            if self.__file != None: #print to file
                print(self.__csv_delim.join(output), file=self.__file)
            else:
                print(self.__csv_delim.join(output))
            self.__msg_count+=1  #increase __msg_count
        self.__prev_data = s #set __prev_data == s
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`output = s` only makes the name `output` point at `s`.

If you want to shallow-copy `s` to `output`, do `output = s[:]` (works for lists, etc.).

Beyond that, it's truthfully very hard to try to follow your program's logic, especially with all of those double underscores that look like line noise...